# Why console.log function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```js
function stringifyObj(parmObj){
    s="";
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parmObj).forEach
    (
        function (val, idx, array) {
          s+=val + ' -> ' + parmObj[val]+"\n";
        }
    )
    return s;
}

var arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
    { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 }
  ];

console.log(
    arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(parmArrItem)
        {
            const p=stringifyObj(parmArrItem);
            console.log(p); 
        }
));
```

In the code below, 2 objects are displayed fine, but after that I get `undefined` displayed at the end of the run. Where does the `undefined` come from? Thanks.

Comment: That's not how [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used.

Comment: You forgot to declare `s` properly. Any variable that is not declared with `var` (or `let`) is top-level global, and that always is a bug. Static code analysis tools like jshint show you these errors, use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`arrayOfObjects.forEach` returns nothing.

So, when you use `console.log()` for a void function that's you received **undefined**.

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method only executes a callback provided function for every item from an array.

With the other words, the `console` prints the result of **evaluating** an **expression**.

`console.log()` is undefined since your function or expression not explicitly return something.

```js
function stringifyObj(parmObj){
    s="";
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parmObj).forEach
    (
        function (val, idx, array) {
          s+=val + ' -> ' + parmObj[val]+"\n";
        }
    )
    return s;
}

var arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
    { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 }
  ];


arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(parmArrItem)
        {
            const p=stringifyObj(parmArrItem);
            console.log(p); 
        }
);
```